# Tunnel from web host to external API

Tags: php, xml, api, tunnel

We have our IP white listed with an external company who allow us access to their API.

The problem is, you can only generate the queries to the API by accessing their control panel - which you need to be white listed to access.

We have hosting with GoDaddy, so obviously the IP that's white listed is one of theirs, so when we try and connect from our office or home, access is denied.

Is there any way to tunnel from the server, to the API?

Any help much appreciated

Comment: do you rent a server / vps, or are you using shared hosting?

Comment: It's shared hosting but we have a dedicated IP address which allows us to access their API

Comment: ok, well that complicates things. You could try http://www.glype.com/ which is a web proxy you can probably install on shared hosting

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to set up a proxy server if you have a dedicated server, from what you said I don't think you have one. So, you need to create an intermediate API and host it on your server to be a broker between you and the destination API. If it's a REST API it's fairly easy to do with PHP cUrl library.

Comment: Yeah it's shared so we don't have immediate access to the actual server. We'll have a look into the PHP curl library suggestions - much appreciated